# How to convert Db2 query result set to an XML file based on a given XSL using IBM DataStage?

Tags: xml-parsing, db2, datastage

Trying to covert a Db2 query result set to an xml file based on xsl. Can we use the below pattern?

DB2 Connector -> XML_Transformer Stage (imported xsl) - XML _Output Stage.

Thanks...R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple options assuming you do not have XML already in your Db2 table, 
you do not need the XML Transformer.

I strongly suggest you use the modern Hierarchical stage (also known as XML stage depending on the version of DataStage) so I would go for following structure if you want a file or files as a target.

Db2 Connect -> Hierarchical stage -> Sequential File stage

In addition, Db2 offers lots of XML functionality to generate XML by using SQL or XQuery.

Comment: Thank you Michael. Our  DataStage version is V11.5, we do have stages "Hierarchical Data", "XML_Input", "XML_Output" and "XML_Transform" stages.  
 While using Hierarchical Data Stage its throwing an error "CDIUW2002E DataStage did not provide the XML stage with a context". Hence I used "XML Output" stage to write the result set in the XML format. "Document Settings - "Generate XML chunk" is checked, Namespace declaration loaded from the xsl from metadata explorer. "Nested Chunk" not sure about it , so included XSL as Text. Job is currently failing to write any sort of XML output. Any leads?